# PHP - Show Array as HTML Table

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code which pulls an array of IP and MAC addresses from my server.

```
<?php
$arpa = shell_exec('arp -a');
$arpa = stristr($arpa, 'Type');
$arpa = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $arpa);
$arpat = explode(" ", $arpa);

list($k, $v) = each($arpat);

while (list($k, $v) = each($arpat))
{
    $ippp = $v;
    list($k, $v) = each($arpat);
    $iddd = $v;
    list($k, $v) = each($arpat);
    $typer = $v;

    if ($v && $iddd && ($typer != "invalid"))
    {
        if($ippp == "Interface:") break; // only process the first group of IP and MAC addresses
        else $arpa_new_status[$iddd]['ip'] = $ippp;
    }
}

// sort it
//ksort($arpa_new_status);
//reset($arpa_new_status);

foreach ($arpa_new_status as $mac => $values)
{
    $ips_array[] = array("mac" => $mac, "ip" => $values['ip']);
}
?>
```

This is what it looks like on my browser, ranging from 0 to 20 in this case.

[image: Array Example]

Now I'm trying to show the array as a nice HTML table.
Any ideas how I can do that using my code structure above?

I started writing some code but it doesn't work at all and I can't figure it out. I'm no PHP expert. I'm more of a C/C++ programmer :P

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $keys = array_keys($ips_array);
            foreach($keys as $key => $value):
            ?>
                <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
            <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $data = array_keys($values);
            foreach($data as $key => $mac):
            ?>
                <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
            <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Something like this is what I'm after

[image: Table Example]

Thanks.

Comment: What happens with current code and what do you want?

Comment: I added an example image of the type of layout I'm after. With the current code, my table looks like garbage (just a value of 0 though 20 on the top row and a single 20 on the second row).

Comment: Do keys in `$data` correspond with `$ips_array` keys?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by keys. Are keys like array indexes?

Comment: Yes, keys/indexs are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Mac</td>
        <td>IP</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($ips_array as $ip_data):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $ip_data['mac'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ip_data['ip'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```